# SQL Counter Loop

Tags: python, sql, oracle

Coming from Python/R but new to SQL...

Is there a way to use 'counter' in a SQL loop?

For example, how can I mimic the following simple Python for-loop in SQL:

```
counter = 7
For i in range(1,conter+1):
    some_function_that_takes_i_as_argument
    counter +=1
```

I am trying to replace a numeric value "i" (in a range) in a SQL query !

Comment: what is "some_function_that_takes_i_as_argument" ? maybe we can write a sql for that without looping

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can only do things like this in stored procedures, which depend on the specific SQL dialect. What RDBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL)?

Comment: @eshirvana in SQL, the query I am trying to use the counter (i) in is "SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE date > SYSDATE - i"...hope this makes sense.

Comment: @FrankYellin in SQL, the query I am trying to use the counter (i) in is "SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE date > SYSDATE - i". I am basically trying to loop through counter and acquire data in different dates... hope that makes sense

Comment: @barmar My RDBMS is Oracle. Could you please elaborate more on what you mean by "stored procedures" please?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch14.htm

Comment: Also remember that you are accessing data from a relational database.  The items in the database have no order, and the database is free to return them to you in any order it wants.  I'm not even sure that SYSDATE - i makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL you need to develop a different way of thinking - not procedural, but in terms of *what is the set* you are looking to get? From your statement SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE date > SYSDATE - i". In his case seems you just want data from the last 8 days (today and 7 days prior). With SQL this is just a single statement (no loop required):

```
select * 
  from table_a 
where date >= trunc(sysdate – 7)
 order by date desc;
```

NOTE:  The above user "date" as a column name. This is an extremely poor choice as **date**  is and Oracle data type as well as an [Oracle and SQL standard reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words.html#GUID-55C49D1E-BE08-4C50-A9DD-8593EB925612).  
The query uses the `trunc` function since the Oracle **date** data type always includes time.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I am ultimately trying to sum the count for each of the past 8 days. That's why I was thinking looping. Since, loop is not an ideal option, how can I achieve this?